# struggling to understanding a piece of code

Tags: python, dataframe

I have this code that assigns each time different set from the list in the train and test set. I am struggling to understand the code.

```
df_list = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6]
for i in range(6):
    train = pd.concat(df_list[0:i] + df_list[i+1:])
    test = df_list[i]
```

Does it say that it goes from `df1[0]` all the way until `df6[5]` and add to this every time one `df`?

Can you please help me to understanding the code?

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/the-basics-of-indexing-and-slicing-python-lists-2d12c90a94cf

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, if `i == 1`, `train` will contain `pd.concat(df_list[0:1] + df_list[2:])` that will become `pd.concat([df1, df3, df4, df5, df6])` and `test` will contain `df_list[1]` that become `df2`.

So generally, in each iteration `train` will contain each dataframe in `df_list` except the dataframe at `i`th index and `test` will contain the dataframe at `i`th index.

Comment: hi thanks for the answer. Just to understand. when you say train will contain each data frame in df_list except the data frame at i th index you mean both the places where i is?
train = pd.concat(df_list[0:i] + df_list[i+1:])

Comment: `pd.concat(df_list[0:i] + df_list[i+1:])` this will never include`i`  because `df[0:i]` in this `i` is exclusive and other part `df_list[i+1:]` it will never include `i` because it will always start from `i+1`

Comment: one last question, please

when i=2

we have df_list [0:2]. so here we take df0 and we exclude df3 which is the position 2 right?

then we say df_list[i+1]=3:) which means that we take df4 which is the position 3, and then df5,df6 which are in the position 4.5

so we concat we take df0 +df4+df5+df6 for the train

df3 goes to test set

where is df2. i am confused

Comment: oh when we say df_list [0:2] we take 0,1 and we exclude 2 right?

Comment: @redplanet yeah `df_list[0:n]` in this `n` will always excluded

Answer (score -1):

although i'm a beginner at python, I think the code `train = pd.concat(df_list[0:i] + df_list[i+1:])` needs to be indented so its part of the i.

the meaning of the code is that from 0 to i (max is 5 because of the range) `pd.concat` (a function that is possibly imported and called upon here) from the variable df_list 0 to whatever i is in the loop and from the variable df_list i+1 and store that result as the variable test.

this would mean that the variable test is changing every time the loop is run. I think it would be better to use `test(i) = df_list[i]`

Comment: Please test before submitting and post working snippets of code. `test(i)` is clearly not ok since `test` is not a function. If you meant create a list and save values, it should be `test[i]`, or `test.append(df_list[i])`.